# Reading From Socket Multiple Times

Tags: dart

I'm having some trouble writing and reading from a socket multiple times. I'm writing a speed test and I essentially want to write an http request using a socket, which will return garbage data which I then read to test the bandwidth speed. I've made the http request successfully, but I'm unable to flip flop between writing to the socket and then reading the response. I can read the data from the socket's stream once, and then it doesn't seem to have any more data to read even after i've made another request.

The salient part of the code is in the `start` method where the loop runs:

```dart
class DownloadTest {
  late Socket socket;
  late Stream<Uint8List> dataStream;
  bool graceTimeOver = false;
  int totalBytesDownloaded = 0;
  late DateTime startTime;
  final ckSize = 10;
  final graceTime = 2;
  final dlTime = 5;
  final client = HttpClient();
  final String _serverAddress;
  final void Function(double mbps) onProgress;

  DownloadTest({required serverAddress, required this.onProgress})
      : _serverAddress = serverAddress;

  Future<void> start() async {
    await resetTest();
    while (true) {
      writeDlRequest();
      var bytesDownloaded = await downloadData();
      print(graceTimeOver);
      if (!graceTimeOver) {
        checkGraceTime();
      } else {
        print(bytesDownloaded);
        totalBytesDownloaded += bytesDownloaded;
        if (testFinished()) {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    print('test over');
    await socket.close();
  }

  Future<int> downloadData() async {
    var bytes = 0;
    await for (var data in dataStream) {
      bytes += data.length;
    }
    return bytes;
  }

  Future<void> resetTest() async {
    socket = await Socket.connect(_serverAddress, 80);
    dataStream = socket.asBroadcastStream();
    graceTimeOver = false;
    startTime = DateTime.now();
    totalBytesDownloaded = 0;
  }

  void checkGraceTime() {
    if (!graceTimeOver) {
      var elapsedSeconds =
          startTime.difference(DateTime.now()).inMilliseconds / 1000;
      if (elapsedSeconds >= graceTime) {
        graceTimeOver = true;
        startTime = DateTime.now();
        print('grace time over');
      }
    }
  }

  void writeDlRequest() {
    socket.write('GET /garbage.php?ckSize=$ckSize HTTP/1.1\r\n');
    socket.write('Host: speedtest.somethingsomething.com:80\r\n');
    socket.write('Connection: keep-alive\r\n');
    socket.write('\r\n');
  }

  bool testFinished() {
    var elapsedSeconds =
        startTime.difference(DateTime.now()).inMilliseconds / 1000;
    return elapsedSeconds >= dlTime;
  }
}
```

I've made the socket's stream into a broadcast stream so I **should** be able to listen to it multiple times, but after reading from it the first time, it fails to read any more data and the loop just spins. Any ideas where i'm going wrong?

Comment: `await for (var data in dataStream)` this will first stop when `dataStream` is "done" which is when the socket is closed since we are then no longer going to receive any more data.

Comment: Can it not be reopened somehow once i've written another request into the socket?

Comment: No, the socket is done so you need to reconnect if you want a new socket. Alternative, you should leave the loop by some other reason (e.g. if the server are returning some kind of code which means you should stop listening for data and start sending some data the other way.

Comment: But I am a little confused about why you are trying to use sockets instead of using the `HttpClient` which can handle a lot of this stuff for you? Since you are calling a PHP script on a HTTP server you are already communicating over the HTTP protocol so why go around the `HttpClient`?

Comment: Ah ok, understood. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Keep-alive is only done by mutual agreement. The server may choose to close the connection even if keep-alive is requested, since keeping a connection open consumes resources.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Not necessarily in your exact case here but there are protocols that require this: one where I had to struggle with this is the LPR protocol for printing. This explicitly requires reading acknowledgment bytes during the process of sending data, without starting a new connection.

The solution was to write my own `BidirectionalSocket` wrapping a `RawSocket`. It keeps two streams inside, created with `StreamSplitter`:

```
StreamSplitter multiStream = StreamSplitter(socket);
Stream readStream = multiStream.split().where((event) => event == RawSocketEvent.read);
StreamIterator readIterator = StreamIterator(readStream);
Stream writeStream = multiStream.split().where((event) => event == RawSocketEvent.write);
StreamIterator writeIterator = StreamIterator(writeStream);
```

You can use one for writing, the other one for reading:

```
socket.writeEventsEnabled = true;
await writeIterator.moveNext();
if (writeIterator.current == RawSocketEvent.write) {
  socket.write(data);
}
socket.writeEventsEnabled = false;
```

and

```
socket.readEventsEnabled = true;
await readIterator.moveNext();
if (readIterator.current == RawSocketEvent.read && socket.available() > 0) {
  return socket.read(length);
}
socket.readEventsEnabled = false;
```